# Why would Ignore default convention not apply to nested child properties in mongodb c#?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

I have two POCO objects:

```
class A
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public B Child { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShouldBeIgnored { get; set; }
}
```

given the following JSON POST Object:

```
{
    "child": {
        "name": "foo"
    }
}
```

This correctly evaluates to my C# models with null values for the missing properties.

I want to convert this to a BsonDocument, so am using `myObject.ToBsonDocument()` to do so.

I have registered the following convention:

```
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfDefault",
            new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true) },
            t => true);
```

I expected all of the default value properties on both the parent and child objects (A and B) to be ignored, but what has been produced is the following:

```
{
    "Child" : {
        "_t" : "B",
        "Name" : "foo",
        "ShouldBeIgnored" : null
    }
}
```

Why would the parent default values be ignored but not the child values?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Solved the issue.

I had registered my class maps BEFORE registering the convention to ignore default values, therefore a classmap not ignoring null values was generated that took precedence over the convention. Changing the application startup lifecycle to register the conventions first solved the problem.